# Having trouble in accessing my virtual machine from local with SSH

Tags: hadoop, networking, ssh, virtual-machine

I've ubuntu 16.04 on both my local and virtual machine, I want to access my virtual machine from my local machine, I've already changed the network adapter to bridge connection (both ips are in 192.168,10.x). But when i run the **ssh virtual_mac_ip** from my local terminal i get the error *ssh: connect to host 192.168.10.7 port 22: Connection refused*.

ps: I want to configure single node hadoop cluster

Comment: SSH server isn't running by default...

Comment: Issue has been resolved

I changed my network adapter to NAT again, and use port forwarding on port 2222. 

Now when I run "ssh -p 2222 username@127.0.0.1", I am able to connect to my guest OS

Comment: Okay. By the way, either the Hortonworks sandbox or Cloudera quickstart VM are both pre-installed Hadoop environments

Comment: Yeah I know I already have a cloudera quickstart one, but I wanted to setup it myself, I think this way I can learn more. 
Thanks @cricket_007

Comment: Depends what you want to learn. If you want a career in Hadoop, you'll almost never be installing it from source. For example, the Hadoop instances in the cloud are all pre-configured. If you want to learn how to program MapReduce or Spark, also not necessary

Comment: Is it so? Thanks man, It was a great help for me, much appreciated :)

Can you provide me a path to follow, as you are experienced and can help me in so many ways

Comment: I'm certified developer in Hortonworks and Cloudera. They both put out decent tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved I changed my network adapter to NAT again, and use port forwarding on port 2222. Now when I run "ssh -p 2222 username@127.0.0.1", I am able to connect to my guest OS

Side note: Please check if OpenSSH is installed on your guess machine